# Add if else-if else block for bgcolor attribute of td table HTML tag

Tags: html

I need to have an implementation where the bgcolor attribute of td tag in table should be changed based on some condition. I need to check of a variable is equal to 'a' bgcolor should be set to 'blue', if it's 'b' bgcolor should be 'black and if it's 'c' bgcolor should be 'red'. 
How this can be achieved in HTML?

Comment: only html can not be done, can be achieved via js or php, depends on what your project is written?

Comment: Show us some code that you have tried.

Comment: show us the condition.

Comment: HTML is a markup language you can not apply any programming logic to it. Instead, you can use JavaScript to fetch the HTML element and put some logic accordingly.

Comment: You *can* achieve this with CSS, by [combining hidden radio buttons, `:checked`, and the sibling selector](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/). You shouldn’t, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing value of input and click button to see change

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <input type="text" id="inputf">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="myvar">Hello</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var input=document.getElementById('inputf').value;
            var elem=document.getElementById('myvar');
            if (input<=10) {
                elem.style.backgroundColor="red";
            } else {
                elem.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```